# cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message

Tags: python, django, websocket, python-asyncio, django-channels

### RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message

hello
I wrote a counsumer that acts as a middleware that connects to the server socket, for example X, then receives the data and adds a series of information to the data, then sends it to the clients connected to the consumer. When the first client connects it works fine and when the second client connects it gives the following error:
RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message

```
class ConnectionManager:
    connection = None
    connection_lock = asyncio.Lock()

    @classmethod
    async def get_connection(cls):
        async with cls.connection_lock:
            if cls.connection is None or not cls.connection.open:
                cls.connection = await cls.create_connection()
            return cls.connection

    @classmethod
    async def create_connection(cls):
        email = "email"
        password = "Password"
        url = "url"

        session = requests.Session()
        params = urlencode({"email": email, "password": password})

        headers = {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "accept": "application/json",
        }

        session.post(url + "/api/session", data=params, headers=headers)

        cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
        token = cookies["JSESSIONID"]
        return await websockets.connect(
                "ws://url",
                ping_interval=None,
                extra_headers=(("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + token),),
            )

class WebsocketConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.message_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()


        await self.channel_layer.group_add("group", self.channel_name)

        asyncio.ensure_future(self.handle_connection())

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard("group", self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        pass

    async def handle_connection(self):
        traccar_connection = await ConnectionManager.get_connection()

        try:
            async for traccar_data in traccar_connection:
                modified_data = self.process_data(traccar_data)

                await self.message_queue.put(modified_data)

                asyncio.ensure_future(self.process_message_queue())
        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
            pass

    async def process_message_queue(self):
        while True:

            modified_data = await self.message_queue.get()
            await self.broadcast_data(modified_data)

    async def broadcast_data(self, data):
        await self.send(str(data))

    @staticmethod
    def process_data(traccar_data):
        processed_data = traccar_data + " - Processed by Django"
        return processed_data
```

Comment: In the `handle_connection` method, each time a client connects, you're starting an asynchronous for loop to listen on the same `traccar_connection`. When the second client connects, it tries to start another listening loop on the same connection, which raises the RuntimeError.